# Specify Table Column Width on a Page

Tags: columns, table

I currently have the following html on my Wordpress page

```
<table border="5">
    <col width="50">
    <col width="100">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>NLP</h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Overview</td>
            <td>A natural language processing challenge.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However the `<col width="50">` seems to be getting ignored. Is this getting overridden by something in the CSS and if so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this?

```
<table border="5">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="150" colspan="2">
            <h4>NLP</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50">Overview</td>
        <td width="100">A natural language processing challenge.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```